# How do I turn off auto-tabbing switch/case in VC2013 for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

in VC2013 auto-formatting for C++, when i using switch/case statements every time auto tabbing so much. It's uncomfortable to seen the code through small workspace. and this is not my code standard of other projects.

Any way, the symptoms this.

```
    switch(pNPCAIAct->m_nActType)
    {
        case MONAIACT_SPAWN_RANDOMPOINT:
        {
                                           if(nSpawnPoint >= 5) break;

                                           nParaMater[nSpawnPoint] = pNPCAIAct->GetActData(0);
                                           nParaMater[5 + nSpawnPoint] = pNPCAIAct->GetActData(1);

                                           ++nSpawnPoint;
        }
        break;
    }
```

normally it should be like...

```
    switch(pNPCAIAct->m_nActType)
    {
        case MONAIACT_SPAWN_RANDOMPOINT:
        {
            if(nSpawnPoint >= 5) break;

            nParaMater[nSpawnPoint] = pNPCAIAct->GetActData(0);
            nParaMater[5 + nSpawnPoint] = pNPCAIAct->GetActData(1);

            ++nSpawnPoint;
        }
        break;
    }
```

this is the what i want result.
can you see the different gap of tabs?

and strange thing is, it's "taaaaaaabbing" only switch/case statement.

It was i what touched some kind of text editor settings.
how do i turn off the "taaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabing"

Comment: Using parentheses in a case statement tends to throw-off the auto-formatter.  Very easy to fix with Edit > Advanced > Format Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled.

DONE......